# Canceling an installation in Inno Setup

Tags: c#, installation, inno-setup

I'm developing an application in C#. I'm trying to create the installation pack using Inno Setup, but I need to check if the user has the .NET framework installed. I did this, but here goes the problem: if the user doesn't want to install the .NET 4, the program needs to cancel the installation. How can I do this?

```pascal
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"; Check: FrameworkIsNotInstalled
Filename: "{app}\sis_visu_ipccV2.0.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,SisIPCCAR4}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  if MsgBox('Foi detectado que seu computador não possui o .NET Framework 4.0. Para que o aplicativo execute normalmente é necessário tê-lo instalado. Deseja instalar? ', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2) = IDYES then
   begin
     Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0');
    end
    else begin
      Abort;
    end; 
end;
```

Comment: In that case I would change the order and perform the .NET Check + display the message right after setup initializes. There is no much sense of installing all files and then... canceling the setup at the very end.

Comment: How can I display the message right after setup initializes? Sorry, but I started using Inno these days. My code doesn't work!

Comment: You can implement or call your Check function in `function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;` and then pass the result (e.g. as `Q`) from Message Box to the Result of this function. E.g. `if Q = IDYES then Result := True);` what will continue the Setup.

Comment: Sorry man, i didn't understand. Where is the function InitializeSetup? And I didn't understand the (e.g as Q) ...

Comment: Please find the example on my Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/8Tf1hhfE

Comment: Hi guy, i'm using your code, but it still doesn't work. The message appears in the beginning of the installation but if I click no, the setup stops, that's ok. But if I click Yes, nothing happens. The installation of .NET doesn't start. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, the setup of . NET initializes but only in the end of the installation of the program. And the message is shown all the time during the process, even if i click yes.

Comment: What do you mean by: "the message is shown all the time during the process"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check and ask for the permission of .NET installation at the very beginning.

If user will choose `NOT` to install .NET, the installation process will be terminated.

If user will `AGREE` to install .NET, the installation process will run normally, and the .NET will be installed at the end of installation (via `RUN` section).

---

You may move it from `RUN` section to `BeforeInstall` or choose other solution, but that would require to write additional piece of code.

---

Example:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; 
 Parameters: "/passive /norestart"; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; 
 StatusMsg: "{cm:dotNetInstallation}"; Check: not dotNetInstalled
Filename: "{app}\sis_visu_ipccV2.0.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,SisIPCCAR4}"; 
 Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[CustomMessages]
dotNETnotpresent=Foi detectado que seu computador não possui o .NET Framework 4.0. Para que o aplicativo execute normalmente é necessário tê-lo instalado. %n%nDeseja instalar? 
dotNetInstallation=Installation of .NET Framework 4.0 in progress...

[Code]
var
    dotNetBool: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Q: Integer;
begin
    Result := False;
    dotNetBool := False;
    if not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0') then begin
    //Registry entry was not found, quesion will appear
        Q := MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:dotNETnotpresent}'), mbInformation, MB_YESNO);      
        if Q = IDYES then begin
        //If the asnwer is YES, Setup will initialize 
        //If the answer is NO, Setup will terminate
            Result := True;
        end;
    end
    else begin
    //Registry entry was found, Setup will initialize
        dotNetBool := True;
        Result := True;
    end;
end;

function dotNetInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := dotNetBool;
end;
```

Comment: It still has a problem. Even in the computers that already have the .NET, the installation of the .NET begins. It says that is repairing. It's the last problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user3628552 - you are right. I forgot about that. Updated code posted.